# Why do my goroutines wait for each other instead of finishing when done?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, go, bubble-sort, goroutine

I'm pretty new to Go and there is one thing in my code which I don't understand.
I wrote a simple bubblesort algorithm (I know it's not really efficient ;)).
Now I want to start 3 GoRoutines. Each thread should sort his array independent from the other ones. When finished, the func. should print a "done"-Message.

Here is my Code:

```
package main 

import (
    "fmt"
    "time" //for time functions e.g. Now()
    "math/rand" //for pseudo random numbers
)


/* Simple bubblesort algorithm*/
func bubblesort(str string, a []int) []int {
    for n:=len(a); n>1; n-- {
        for i:=0; i<n-1; i++ {
            if a[i] > a[i+1] {
                a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i] //swap
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(str+" done") //done message
    return a
}

/*fill slice with pseudo numbers*/
func random_fill(a []int) []int {
    for i:=0; i<len(a); i++ { 
        a[i] = rand.Int()
    }
    return a
}

func main() {
   rand.Seed( time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()) //set seed for rand.

   a1 := make([]int, 34589) //create slice
   a2 := make([]int, 42) //create slice
   a3 := make([]int, 9999) //create slice

   a1 = random_fill(a1) //fill slice
   a2 = random_fill(a2) //fill slice
   a3 = random_fill(a3) //fill slice
   fmt.Println("Slices filled ...")

   go bubblesort("Thread 1", a1) //1. Routine Start
   go bubblesort("Thread 2", a2) //2. Routine Start
   go bubblesort("Thread 3", a3) //3. Routine Start
   fmt.Println("Main working ...")

   time.Sleep(1*60*1e9) //Wait 1 minute for the "done" messages
}
```

This is what I get:

```
Slices filled ...
Main working ...
Thread 1 done
Thread 2 done
Thread 3 done
```

Should'nt Thread 2 finish first, since his slice is the smallest?
It seems that all the threads are waiting for the others to finish, because the "done"-messages appear at the same time, no matter how big the slices are..

Where is my brainbug? =)

Thanks in advance.

*Edit:
When putting "time.Sleep(1)" in the for-loop in the bubblesort func. it seems to work.. but I want to clock the duration on different machines with this code (I know, i have to change the random thing), so sleep would falsify the results.

Comment: As you are new to Go, I suggest you use channels for managing synchronization : read http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#concurrency. It's a really neat core feature of Go, which will usually let you avoid using active waiting or time.Sleep().

Comment: Also note that `rand` has a mutex lock which will harm your concurrent performance; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298523/why-does-adding-concurrency-slow-down-this-golang-code

Comment: thanks too, i fixed that

Comment: See also very related questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314317/whats-wrong-with-my-golang-code/12323208 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413510/why-is-this-golang-code-blocking/12413618

Comment: An interesting bit of history about how successive versions of Go handle this https://youtu.be/1I1WmeSjRSw?t=93

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, there is no garantee regarding the order in which your goroutines will be executed.

However if you force the true parallel processing by explicitly letting 2 processor cores run :

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time" //for time functions e.g. Now()
    "math/rand" //for pseudo random numbers
    "runtime"
)
...

func main() {
   runtime.GOMAXPROCS(2)

   rand.Seed( time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()) //set seed for rand.
...
```

Then you will get the expected result :

```
Slices filled ...
Main working ...
Thread 2 done
Thread 3 done
Thread 1 done
```

Best regards

Comment: Please note this was the best answer for Go up to 1.1 . Things have changed in december 2013 : see [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399378/why-do-my-goroutines-wait-for-each-other-instead-of-finishing-when-done/20836408#20836408)

Answer (score 3):

The important thing is the ability to "yield" the processor to other processes, before the whole potentialy long-running workload is finished. This holds true as well in single-core context or multi-core context (because [Concurrency is not the same as Parallelism](http://blog.golang.org/2013/01/concurrency-is-not-parallelism.html)).

This is exactly what the [runtime.Gosched()](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Gosched) function does :

> Gosched yields the processor, allowing other goroutines to run. It
>   does not suspend the current goroutine, so execution resumes
>   automatically.

Be aware that a "context switch" is not free : it costs a little time each time.

- On my machine without yielding, your program runs in 5.1s.
- If you yield in the outer loop (`for n:=len(a); n>1; n--`), it runs in 5.2s : small overhead.
- If you yield in the inner loop (`for i:=0; i<n-1; i++`), it runs in 61.7s : huge overhead !!

Here is the modified program correctly yielding, with the small overhead :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

/* Simple bubblesort algorithm*/
func bubblesort(str string, a []int, ch chan []int) {
    for n := len(a); n > 1; n-- {
        for i := 0; i < n-1; i++ {
            if a[i] > a[i+1] {
                a[i], a[i+1] = a[i+1], a[i] //swap
            }
        }
        runtime.Gosched() // yield after part of the workload
    }
    fmt.Println(str + " done") //done message
    ch <- a
}

/*fill slice with pseudo numbers*/
func random_fill(a []int) []int {
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        a[i] = rand.Int()
    }
    return a
}

func main() {
    rand.Seed(time.Now().UTC().UnixNano()) //set seed for rand.

    a1 := make([]int, 34589) //create slice
    a2 := make([]int, 42)    //create slice
    a3 := make([]int, 9999)  //create slice

    a1 = random_fill(a1) //fill slice
    a2 = random_fill(a2) //fill slice
    a3 = random_fill(a3) //fill slice
    fmt.Println("Slices filled ...")

    ch1 := make(chan []int) //create channel of result
    ch2 := make(chan []int) //create channel of result
    ch3 := make(chan []int) //create channel of result

    go bubblesort("Thread 1", a1, ch1) //1. Routine Start
    go bubblesort("Thread 2", a2, ch2) //2. Routine Start
    go bubblesort("Thread 3", a3, ch3) //3. Routine Start
    fmt.Println("Main working ...")

    <-ch1 // Wait for result 1
    <-ch2 // Wait for result 2
    <-ch3 // Wait for result 3
}
```

Output :

```
Slices filled ...
Main working ...
Thread 2 done
Thread 3 done
Thread 1 done
```

I also used channels to implement the rendez-vous, as suggested in my previous comment.

Best regards :)

Comment: Thank you, especially for the link "Concurrency is not the same as Parallelism". that was not this clear before!

Answer (score 3):

Since the release of Go 1.2, the original program now <s>works</s> *may work* fine without modification. You may try it in [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/n3Mh86QfiC).

This is explained in the [Go 1.2 release notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.2#preemption) :

> In prior releases, a goroutine that was looping forever could starve
>   out other goroutines on the same thread, a serious problem when
>   GOMAXPROCS provided only one user thread. In Go 1.2, this is partially
>   addressed: The scheduler is invoked occasionally upon entry to a
>   function.

Comment: In fact it is not so obvious this fact helps. There is no function call inside `bubblesort`, so the starvation problem is still there. And the (cached) output in the Playground is still 1, then 2, then 3.

Comment: FWIW with Go 1.8+ I've only witnessed the expected behavior "Thread 2 done Thread 3 done Thread 1 done", even when runtime.GOMAXPROCS(1)