# Is there a simple `parallel for` in golang like OpenMP?

Tags: c, go, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to optimise a puzzle with parallel processing, for better performance.

Ideally, in C99 w/ OpenMP, I should be able to do that with the help of a `#pragma omp parallel for` prior to a `for` loop in question, and then it should be up to the system to distribute the load between the CPUs.

The official documentation for Go at https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#parallel, however, seems to suggest that for parallel processing I must, (0), manually get the number of cores from the runtime environment, (1), loop over said cores, (2), effectively code up a distinct for loop for each core, (3), loop over the cores once again to make sure all the stuff got processed.

Am I missing something?  For the simplest case, is OpenMP with the ancient C superior to the brand new Go that's touted as C's best replacement?  For a more complicated example, how exactly do you split up a `range` between the CPUs?

Comment: @Amd, superficial edits (as well as introducing spelling mistakes) are against ToS

Answer (score 6):

Effective Go is outdated about that, Go automatically sets GOMAXPROCS to the number of processors (you can still manually set it to force the number you want).

Here's a very simple example for parallel processing of a slice:

```
data := make([]float64, SZ)
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := range data {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(v *float64) {
        // note that using rand is a bad example because global rand uses a mutex
        *v = rand.Float64()
        wg.Done()
    }(&data[i])
}
wg.Wait()
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/ftWkAhCf9k)

Comment: looks good, however, i've tried it, and it doesn't seem to offer any performance increase, my for loop over about 2k elements actually runs 39 seconds and still uses only 12.5% of CPU (according to top), whereas a non-go-routine version completes in 29 seconds.

Comment: @cnst http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298523/why-does-adding-concurrency-slow-down-this-golang-code

Comment: Note also that this example code, above, is creating goroutines. Please understand that goroutines are not like native operating system threads, they are an abstraction above them. The runtime time-slices the goroutines across cpu cores, avoiding you from doing that explicitly. In many cases, having an excess number of goroutines w.r.t the number of cores is a good thing (indeed there is theoretical work to support this [Valiant and others]).